# LitElement Dot with HTML elements attribute/property

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element, polymer-3.x

I am learning web components using Polymer. I am a beginner in web development.

How can I understand what does dot notation means in `.checked` attributes or property of HTML element?

```
<input id="state" type="radio" name=${this.group} .checked=${this.checked} />
```

Answer (score 12):

Overall the binding type consists of these character prefixes: `.prop`, `?optional` and `@event`.

```
html`<input 
    id="state" 
    type="radio" 
    name=${this.group} 
    @change=${onChange}
    ?required=${required}
    .checked=${this.checked} />`
```

You can insert JavaScript expressions as placeholders for HTML text content, attributes, Boolean attributes, properties, and event handlers.

- Text content: `<p>${...}</p>`
- Attribute: `<p id="${...}"></p>`
- Boolean attribute: `?disabled="${...}"`
- Property: `.value="${...}"`
- Event handler: `@event="${...}"`

[lit-element documentation](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates#bind-properties-to-templated-elements:%7E:text=)%3B-,Bind%20properties%20to%20templated%20elements,You%20can,-insert%20JavaScript%20expressions%20as%20placeholders%20for%20HTML%20text%20content%2C%20attributes%2C%20Boolean%20attributes%2C%20properties%2C%20and%20event%20handlers.)

**[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/question-61490521)**

Comment: Thank you very much. Nicely explained with example. I understood it well.

Comment: While you use double quotes around properties and others in the explanation, you don't use it in the example. Any reason? (Actually, the documentation includes double quotes)