# Printing a property from html tag

Tags: javascript, lit-element

Say you have something like this:

```
<input id="state" type="radio" name=${this.group} .checked=${this.checked} />
```

(Code from [LitElement Dot with HTML elements attribute/property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490521/litelement-dot-with-html-elements-attribute-property) as I was researching what the dot meant)

Is it possible to print out what `${this.checked}` is? If so, how?

Clarification: Is it possible to print it from, for example, another file?

Like if you wanted the id, it would be something like this.input.getAttribute('id'), but for the .checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `${this.checked}` where you want to display it ?

```
<input id="state" type="radio" name=${this.group} .checked=${this.checked} />
(checked: ${this.checked})
```

Comment: Oops, should have clarified, is it possible to print it from, for example, another file?

Like if you wanted the id, it would be something like this.input.getAttribute('id'), but for the .checked

Comment: if you have a reference to the DOM element, you can do `element.checked` or `element.group` etc.